# Подгрузка недостающих символов в кастомном шрифте

Tags: java, javafx

Имеется шрифт:

```
label.setFont(Font.loadFont(Test.class.getResource("font1.otf").toExternalForm(), size));
```

Когда применяем его на Label то происходит следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Каким образом можно подгрузить недостающие символы из другого шрифта или системного?